# Is it possible to get Events associated with a DOM Element in JavaScript(not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, browser

I have one script file which will be injected to any website on the fly. I don't have access to that website code. What i want to do is when someone click on any Element of web page, the list of events associated with that element should be displayed.

In DOM 3 spec, earlier it was mentioned to add EventListenerList. But unfortunately it was removed from specification.

I have already checked **Visual Event 2**. But they are only able to steal events of custom libraries and DOM events with **on** attribute.

In jQuery 1.8+ also we can easily access events of element using

```
$._data(element,'events');
```

In chrome, we can access it using

```
getEventListeners(element)
```

If i had access to webpage then i can override prototype's addEventListener method like

```
HTMLElement.prototype.realAddEventListener = HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener;                              
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = function(a,b,c){ 
    this.realAddEventListener(a,b,c); 
    //do whatever want
};
```

But this is not the case with me as i am not able to inject this code before event listener binding.  Can any one help me for **Vanilla JS**?

Answer (score -1):

you can handle your event with javascript DOM (without JQuery)

```
document.getElementById('my_element').onclick=function(event){
    //TO DO: the behavior of your action
}
```

I hope my answer will be helpfull